# How to write Foreign Key to an attribute of other model?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a model that joins two tables in my DB. When writing the foreign keys like this:

```
fromnode = models.ForeignKey(znode.code)
tonode = models.ForeignKey(znode.code)
```

there is an error: `type object 'znode' has no attribute 'code'`, but there is such an attribute in `znode`:

```
class znode(models.Model):
    code = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535, blank=True, primary_key=True)
```

How do I write this correctly?

Comment: use model name `fromnode = models.ForeignKey(znode)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the class name `znode` instead of `znode.code`. Django automatically adds an id column to every model which will be used as reference as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

> Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name. In the above example, the database table for the Car model will have a manufacturer_id column.

Also you should use CamelCaseClassNames to meet [pep8 coding style conventions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).